# title url and chevron in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I have a problem with the `title_url` helper.
I charge a lot of product and my url has type of : `:any-:num.html`

It's good but `:any` is a product title and occasionally, it's :

```
http://domain.com/Ballon-solair**e<5**00liter-5464.html
```

And the `<` followed by a number broke the url.

I have change the `application/config/foreign_chars.php` and add:

```
'/\</' => '',
```

but it's don't work.

Note : if I has a space between the `<` and the number (`solaire < 500`) it's work normally

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I solved this problem by overloading the `title_url()` helper with my version that uses `iconv()` to replace accented letters with non-accented similar letters then strips/replaces non-alphabetic characters from the provided string and then calls the original implementation of `title_url()` to complete the job.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. So it's not possible to do that with native CI function ?